# Ember.js map action keyUp event

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying out Ember.js but I'm stuck when using actions.

If I use the following:

```html
<button {{action "test"}}>Test</button>
```

And create a controller:

```js
App.NewController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        test: function() {
            console.log("test");
        },
    }
});
```

Then everything works fine and I can see `test` in my log. However, when I try the following:

```html
<input type="text" {{action "test2" on="keyUp"}} />
```

And define the `test2` action in a similar way:

```js
App.NewController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        test: function() {
            console.log("test");
        },
        test2: function() {
            console.log("test2");
        }
    }
});
```

Then it doesn't seem to work. My test button is working, but the keyup event handler is not fired as I expected after reading [the documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_specifying-the-type-of-event).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's really weird, I'll keep looking into it, but you could just use the input helper and observe the value, additionally you could extend the textfield and get the keyup there if you care about which key they are pressing.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EBoLEZe/1/edit

`{{input value=name}}`

```
  postKey: function(){
    console.log(this.get('name'));  
  }.observes('name')
```

See also: [KeyPress event not working as expected in Ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580578/keypress-event-not-working-as-expected-in-ember/19581119#19581119)

Comment: Thanks, I used the first method (with the `postKey`). I will try the other approach (from the linked answer) later. Is that solution preferable or doesn't it matter?

Comment: It depends on what you need.  If all you care about is when the field changes, and not when someone presses shift, or ctrl or something random like that, I think this solution is simpler.  If you want to really know when any key goes up (like the enter key) then the other solution is better.

Comment: @Kingpin2k: is there any way to introduce delay. Currently as user press the key, we call the function. Now I want to ensure when user takes a pause or done typing then only i should call the function, instead of calling the function on every key down

Comment: Add debounce in the observes.  You can debounce another method that is only fired when they pause/stop typing. (Sorry I'm on a phone, so hard to give an example)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a bug (or at least very odd behavior) affecting the ability to use actions with keyboard events. Normally, actions handlers for non-keyboard events (like the default "click" event) don't work when modifier keys are pressed. In your code, if you add `allowedKeys="any"` to your action helper, then your handler will get invoked.

Fiddle: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oyEpImI/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: My fix for this was just merged into Ember https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/567aafa8f0de6b29d90d8638f2166b8df6275f9c