# Calculating dependent input values

Tags: ember.js

My goal is to calculate margin in percent between base price and selling price. But I also want to be able to recalculate price when margin changes. I can't just observe changes via `property()`, because price and margin will recalculate each other infinitely. Instead, I want to run calculations on `keyup` and `change` events, exactly how I implemented same task in JQuery.
But Ember seems doesn't support such events for `input` helper. Only `keypress` supportet, and I can't implement desired behaviour with `keypress`.

Template:

```
{{input value=basePrice placeholder='Base Price' action="updateMarginPercent" on="key-press"}}
{{input value=price placeholder='Price' action="updateMarginPercent" on="key-press"}}
{{input value=marginPercent placeholder='Margin Percent' action="updatePrice" on="key-press"}}
```

Controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  basePrice: 100,
  price: 100,
  marginPercent: 0,
  actions: {
    updateMarginPercent: function() {
      debugger;
      this.set('marginPercent', (this.get('price') - this.get('basePrice')) * 100.0 / this.get('basePrice'));
    },
    updatePrice: function() {
      this.set('price', this.get('basePrice') * (this.get('marginPercent') + 100) / 100);
    }
  }
});
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/yevar/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to extend the text field component to support `key-up`

```
App.KeyUpInputComponent = Em.TextField.extend({
  keyUp: function(event){
    // I chose to send these things, you could just send nothing
    this.sendAction('key-up', event, this.get('value'));
  }
});


{{key-up-input value=asdf key-up='keyUpAction'}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/didisuneka/1/edit?html,js,output

Your jsbin

http://jsbin.com/xedaxageze/1/edit

errrr, I realized I've already answered this before, c'est la vie... [KeyPress event not working as expected in Ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580578/keypress-event-not-working-as-expected-in-ember/19581119#19581119)

Comment: I've actually seen your answer, but haven't understood how to apply it to my situation. Thank you for showing it with my jsbin! I also need to handle `change` event, but it was easy to add: http://jsbin.com/yutuvi/2/edit